# scrape & regex match doesn't work

Tags: php, regex

Ok, I have page with something like this (I added 'scrapehere' string to make it easier to navigate, this page isn't 100% correct html and it has two identical fields with different values. No, I can't fix it because it's cms i'm using and i feel it would be too complicated for me to do):

```
scrapehere<input type="hidden" id="_someid" name="_somename" value="value"/>
```

I'm trying to get hidden value. So I wrote such script:

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents('scrape-test.html');
$regex = '/scrapehere<input type="hidden" id="_someid" name="_somename" value="(.+?)"/';
preg_match($regex,$data,$match);
var_dump($match);
echo $match[1];
?>
```

But instead of my value script outputs this:

```
array(2) { [0]=>  string(74) "scrapehere  string(5) "value" } value
```

What's wrong with it, why won't it just print value? Did it already saved it somewhere but my echo is wrong? I want output to be just `value`.

Comment: I think something went wrong with the < sign in your code.

Comment: maybe that's it... so how do i fix this? any ideas?

Comment: You also probably want ([^"]*) instead of "value".

Comment: sorry, that was my error while copying and pasting, heh... i have (.+?) actually - is it good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var_dump($match);
echo $match[1];
```

both of these lines output data. `var_dump` outputs an array first element of which contains an input tag, which is not displayed in the browser because it's hidden!

so, if you want output to be only `'value'`, remove `var_dump($match);` from your code and let the `echo` do the job.

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

```
<?php
$data = 'scrapehere<input type="hidden" id="_someid" name="_somename" value="value"/>';
$regex = '/scrapehere<input type="hidden" id="_someid" name="_somename" value="value"/';
preg_match($regex,$data,$match);
print_r($match);
echo $match[1];
?>
```

I get this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => scrapehere<input type="hidden" id="_someid" name="_somename" value="value"
)
```

Exactly what I was expecting. What are the contents of your scrape-test.html file?

Comment: it has form and inside this form there is this field: 

scrapehere<input type="hidden" id="_someid" name="_somename" value="value"/>