# PHP : curl get the value of hidden input by regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

How can I get the value of a hidden input which is in the curl response

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="b93779b0fd991381de4b67d60a2c4cd948ad1dc9" />
```

I tried this

```
  $rets = curl_exec($ch);
if (preg_match("/csrf_token/", $rets, $spoof)){
 print_r($spoof);
 // here it found it but can't get the value
}
```

and I tried this one

```
 if(preg_match("/name=\"csrf_token\" value='([a-zA-z0-9]{32})'/", $rets, $spoof)) 

  //empty respown

    {
```

so, what can I do to solve this ?

Comment: Why would you need to use curl to get the csrf token? smells a bit fishy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scrape & regex match doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499118/scrape-regex-match-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you almost had it but the value in your example is between double quotes and your regex expects it in single quotes.
Try this:

```
if (preg_match("/name=\"csrf_token\" value=\"([a-zA-z0-9]{32})\"/", $rets, $spoof))
```